# Import Error from binary dependency file

Tags: python, import, undefined-symbol, dawg

I am attempting to run a package after installing it, but am getting this error:

`ImportError: /home/brownc/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dawg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

The `dawg....gnu.so` file is binary and so it doesn't give much information when opened in sublime.  I don't know enough about binary files in order to go in and remove the line or fix it.  Is there a simple fix for this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for my very specific case, for anyone that may run into this case as well:

I am using Anaconda (python 3 version) and installing the package with `conda install -c package package` worked instead of `pip install package`.

I hope this helps someone.